# Using map and grep to find file names with underscores

Tags: regex, perl

My Perl script searches a directory for file names using the **map** and **grep** expressions. The script works, but I want to also specify in the **map** and **grep** expressions that ALL outputted file names must also include underscores in their names. Sounds simple enough, but I can't figure out how to do this. Please advise. Thanks.

Here's my original script that fails to limit outputted file names to only those with underscores in their names:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
opendir(my $DIR, $dir);
my @files =
   map s/1//rg,
      grep /^[^2-9]*\.png\z/i,
        readdir($DIR);

foreach my$file (@files) {
   print "$file\n";
}
```

Here's the output. Notice how file names without underscores such as "Asarumcanadense.png" are unwantingly outputted:

```
Ilex_verticillata.png
Asarum_canadense.png
Ageratina_altissima.png
Lonicera_maackii.png
Chelone_obliqua.png
Asarumcanadense.png
```

Modifying the map/grep expression as below to include only file names with underscores in the middle of their names created a syntax error:

```
my @files =
 map s/*_*1//rg,
    grep /^_*[^2-9]*\.png\z/i,
      readdir($DIR); # outputted files must also include an underscore
```

Again, please advise how to specify in the **map** and **grep** expressions that ALL outputted file names must also include underscores in their names. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the needed condition to `grep`:

```
my @files =
   map { s/1//rg }
      grep { /^[^2-9]*\.png\z/i && /_/ } 
        readdir($DIR);
```

Comment: Thanks, Timur. Your expression works, but interestingly my "Script Output.log" returns "Useless use of non-destructive substitution (s///r) in void context...". As a beginner, I don't understand the meaning of this warning. Should I be concerned?

Comment: @Jeff Thank you, your original `map` was actually correct. My addition of `$str` to it is only needed in older Perl versions, but generates a warning now. Since Perl 5.14, there is an `/r` flag, which you used, and which does exactly what you intended. See: https://www.perl.com/pub/2011/05/new-features-of-perl-514-non-destructive-substitution.html/ , https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick#Search-and-replace . I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Timur, for the clarification!

Comment: I should have removed `$str` completely (the remains of my first version). Fixed now. Sorry about the confusion I caused with my pre-5.14 code!

Comment: Thanks, again, Timur. Your revised map/grep expression is now working!!!